# Как сделать динамический аргумент лямбды?

Tags: c++

Есть вот такой класс:

```
class Lora {
    public:
        template<typename T>
        void onReceive(std::function<void(T t)> cb1);
};
```

Тело `onReceive`:

```
template<typename T>
void Lora::onReceive(std::function<void(T t)> cb1) {

}
```

Почему у меня не получается сделать вот так?

```
lora.onReceive<LoraMesh>([](LoraMesh message) {
    info("mac %s", message.toChar());
});
```

Компилятор ругается, что

> undefined reference to `void
> Lora::onReceive(std::function<void
> (LoraMesh)>)'

---

Решение: тело должно быть в .h файле

Comment: А где тело `onReceive`?

Comment: Добавил описание

Comment: Всё понятно, тело надо было в хедер поместить.